# How to execute promises sequentially, passing the parameters from an array?

Tags: javascript

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

function myPromise(num){
  return new Promise(res => {
    window.setTimeout(()=>{
      res(  console.log("done: " + num)  )
    },2000)
  })
}


myPromise(myArray[0])
  .then(x => myPromise(myArray[1]))
  .then(x => myPromise(myArray[2]))
  .then(x => myPromise(myArray[3]))
  .then(x => myPromise(myArray[4]))
  .then(x => myPromise(myArray[5]))
```

Right now, if I execute the statement above, it will run sequentially. In my actual use case the array is dynamically populated and I need to execute the `myPromise()` function for each member in `myArray`.

How can I make a "pauseable loop" that will loop for each item in the array, execute `myPromise` and wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing to the next iteration?

Comment: Promise.All is what you want

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can make the repeated application of `.then` into a fold pretty neatly if you’re okay with creating as many promises as array elements as is the case in the question:

```
myArray.reduce(
  (p, x) =>
    p.then(() => myPromise(x)),
  Promise.resolve()
)
```

but given support, an async function is a better choice. It’s nicely readable and has O(1) instead of O(n) memory overhead.

```
const forEachSeries = async (iterable, action) => {
  for (const x of iterable) {
    await action(x)
  }
}

forEachSeries(myArray, myPromise)
```

If you want to collect the return values as an array, that’s:

```
const mapSeries = async (iterable, fn) => {
  const results = []

  for (const x of iterable) {
    results.push(await fn(x))
  }

  return results
}
```

or, without async function support,

```
const mapSeries = (iterable, fn) => {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]()
  const results = []
  const go = () => {
    const {value, done} = iterator.next()

    if (done) {
      return results
    }

    return fn(value).then(mapped => {
      results.push(mapped)
      return go()
    })
  }

  return Promise.resolve().then(go)
}
```

Runnable snippet:

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(res, ms)
  })

const myPromise = num =>
  sleep(500).then(() => {
    console.log('done: ' + num)
  })

const forEachSeries = async (iterable, action) => {
  for (const x of iterable) {
    await action(x)
  }
}

forEachSeries(myArray, myPromise)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('all done!')
  })
```

Comment: If you need all the results returned like with `Promise.all` - `myArray.reduce((p, x) => p.then(results => fn(x).then(r => results.concat(r))), Promise.resolve([])).then(results => {});`

Comment: @JaromandaX: Don’t do that – it’s O(n²) time and gives inconsistent results when the return values are arrays. I’ve added the correct version to the answer.

Comment: How is it O(n²)

Comment: @JaromandaX: The number of copies `concat` makes is 1, then 2, then 3, …. Rule of thumb: never `reduce` with a `concat` or spread.

Comment: Oh, lol, didn't even look at concat :p

Answer (score 29):

Don't create an array of promises. Create an array of functions returning a promise.

```
const f = x => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(x)), 2000))

(async () => {
    for (let job of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map(x => () => f(x)))
        await job()
})()
```

Promises start running immediately after creation.  Therefore, sequential execution is ensured by constructing the next promise only after finishing the current one.

Comment: Neat trick transforming the array for iteration within the for loop clause itself. I like this kind of code but if I'm working with others I'd split it into two statements for readability

Answer (score 12):

*I know I am very late, and my answer is similar to what others have posted. But I thought I could post a clearer answer which may help any beginner.*

Instead of using promises directly, we can use promise factory. Since the promise starts executing as soon as they are created using promise factory we delay the creation of promise.

In this example I create 5 which resolve after a second. I use a promiseCreator to create promises. Now the array `promises` uses `promiseCreator` to create 5 instances of promises. But array `promiseFactories` wraps `promiseCreator` in a function so promise is not invoked immediately. It is invoked when used.

Function `executeSequentially` executes all `promiseLike` sequentially.

- When `promise` array  is passed result is `promise` array itself executes parallely (actually they executed as soon as they are created, not when this line is called).
- When `promiseFactory` array is passed result is new Promise is created when earlier promise has completed their execution.

```js
const promiseCreator = (i, time, text) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
        () => resolve(console.log(`${i} ${text}`)),
        time)
    );
}

const promises = [
    promiseCreator(1, 1000, "parallel"),
    promiseCreator(2, 1000, "parallel"),
    promiseCreator(3, 1000, "parallel"),
    promiseCreator(4, 1000, "parallel"),
    promiseCreator(5, 1000, "parallel"),
]

const promiseFactories = [
    () => promiseCreator(1, 1000, "sequential"),
    () => promiseCreator(2, 1000, "sequential"),
    () => promiseCreator(3, 1000, "sequential"),
    () => promiseCreator(4, 1000, "sequential"),
    () => promiseCreator(5, 1000, "sequential"),
]

function executeSequentially(promiseLikeArray) {
    var result = Promise.resolve();
    promiseLikeArray.forEach(function (promiseLike) {
        result = result.then(promiseLike);
    });
    return result;
}

executeSequentially(promises)
executeSequentially(promiseFactories)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your example on how to call a promise sequentially? Say, I have a promise called "myPromise", which I wanted to call sequentially 5 times with different arguments.

Comment: Doesn't the example already does that. The promises or promiseFactory(s) which are passed to `executeSequentially` have different argument. Can you clarify in which part you are confused. Happy to help. Also I concur `executeSequentially` is rater poor choice of words for that function. Its more like `tryToExecuteSequentiallty` because it ultimately depends upon whether promises are passed or promise factories are passed.

Answer (score 6):

Also you can do it via recursive approach - `executeSequentially` calls itself:

```js
function createPromise(x) {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(x)
      res(x);
    }, x * 1000)
  })
}

function executeSequentially(array) {  
  return createPromise(array.shift())
    .then(x => array.length == 0 ? x : executeSequentially(array));
}

console.time('executeSequentially');
executeSequentially([1, 2, 3]).then(x => {
  console.log('last value: ' + x);
  console.timeEnd('executeSequentially');
});
```

Comment: recursive approach is useful if the array can change during execution. using Array.reduce generates all the executor functions right away while the recursive method here produces each executor function after the last promise is resolved.

Comment: This takes O(n²) time because of the `shift` and mutates its input, which are both subtle traps. Better to use an incrementing index.

Answer (score 6):

#### Sequential:

you can use `async await` features to run promises sequentially . here's a snippet

```
async function chainPromiseCalls(asyncFunctions=[],respectiveParams=[]){

    for(let i=0;i<asyncFunctions.length;i++){
        const eachResult = await asyncFunctions[i](...respectiveParams[i]);
        // do what you want to do with each result 
       
    }

    return ;
}
```

#### Parallel:

for parallel you can just call each async function once in a loop , but if you do want to get their combined result , you can use `Promise.all`

```
function parallelPromiseCalls(asyncFunctions=[],respectiveParams=[]){
    return Promise.all(asyncFunctions.map((func,index)=>func(...respectiveParams[index])))
       .then(resultsList=>{
        resultsList.forEach((result,index)=>{
           // do what you want to do with each result in the list
        })
        return ;
    })
}
```

**note** : I am considering respective parameters as an list of lists since multiple parameters should be passed to any one of the function , else if you have to pass only a single parameter to each then you can remove the spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
//type: [number]
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] //doesn't really matter

//type: number -> Promise<number>
function myPromise(num){
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    window.setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve(console.log("done: " + num)  )
    },2000)
  })
}

//Array.reduce has type: [a] ~> ((b, a) -> b), b) -> b
//So it can have type:
//[number] ~> ((Promise<number>, number) -> Promise<number>), Promise<number>) -> Promise<number>
//Therefore we need to give reduce a function that takes a Promise 
//resolving to a number and a number which makes a new promise.
//This is the function we want:

function sequencePromises(promise, number) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(promise.then(_ => myPromise(number)));
  });
} 

myArray.reduce(sequencePromises, Promise.resolve());
```

Of course, this simplistic approach won't work if you have a promise which can error, or if you need previous results, so you might want to make `sequencePromises` more generic:

```
function genericSequencePromises(promiseFunction) {
  return (promise, parameter) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
                         return promiseFunction(resolve, 
                                                reject, 
                                                promise, 
                                                parameter));
  }
}
```

Then you can do whatever you want as long as you return a Promise.

Finally, you might benefit from this little helper:

```
function promiseSeries(array, reducer) {
  return array.reduce(reducer, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Bringing it all together:

```
let sequencePromises = genericSequencePromises((resolve, reject, promise, num) => {
  resolve(promise.then(_ => console.log(`done: ${num}`)));
}

promiseSeries(myArray, sequencePromises);
```

This way, you can not only handle the case in your question, but much more complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

I enhanced the solution of Master Chief to also return the results as Array. This would be the TypeScript answer:

````ts
/**
 * Executes a list of promises sequentially.
 *
 * Accepts a list of promise factories.
 *
 * @example
 * ```
 * const promiseCreator = (i: number, time: number, text: string) => {
 *   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
 *     () => resolve(console.log(`${i} ${text}`)),
 *     time)
 *   );
 * };
 *
 * const promiseFactories = [
 *   () => promiseCreator(1, 1000, "sequential"),
 *   () => promiseCreator(2, 1000, "sequential"),
 *   () => promiseCreator(3, 1000, "sequential"),
 *   () => promiseCreator(4, 1000, "sequential"),
 *   () => promiseCreator(5, 1000, "sequential"),
 * ];
 *
 * sequentialPromises(promiseFactories);
 * ```
 *
 * @template T
 * @param {(() => Promise<T>)[]} promiseFactories
 * @return {Promise<T[]>}
 */
export const sequentialPromises = <T>(promiseFactories: (() => Promise<T>)[]): Promise<T[]> | undefined => {
  let promiseChain: Promise<T> | undefined;
  const results: T[] = [];
  promiseFactories.forEach((promiseFactory) => {
    promiseChain = (!promiseChain ? promiseFactory() : promiseChain.then(promiseFactory)).then((result) => {
      results.push(result);
      return result;
    });
  });

  return promiseChain?.then(() => results);
};
````

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concise way using Array.reduce and async/await. Taking the eg array and myPromise function from OP:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

function myPromise(num) {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(console.log("done: " + num));
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```

if your myPromise fn does not return result, then

```
myArray.reduce(async (a, b) => {
  await a;
  await myPromise(b);
}, null);
```

this can be easily modified to accumulate result. Eg, if your myPromise were to return a result, you could accumulate them in an array, in the order of myArray elements:

```
const resultArray = myArray.reduce(
   async (a, b) => [...(await a), await myPromise(b)],
   []
);
```

or an object

```
const resultObject = myArray.reduce(async (a, b) => ({
  async (a, b) => ({
    ...(await a),
    [b]: await myPromise(b),
  }),
  {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a loop or recursion to execute the promises one by one(sequence). Here's an example using a recursive function

```
// Example array of other tasks (task should be a promises)
const promises = [
 () => asyncFunction1(),
 () => asyncFunction2(),
 () => asyncFunction3(),
 // Add more functions if needed
];
```

The Recursive function

```
async function executePromisesInSequence(promises) {
if (promises.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  const promise = promises.shift(); // Get the first task to be executed
  await promise(); // Execute the task and wait for it to complete
  await executePromisesInSequence(promises); // Recursively call the function with the remaining tasks
}
```

Finally call function to start running the promises in sequence

```
executePromisesInSequence(promises)
  .then(() => {
    console.log("All promises are completed.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", err);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `babel` and do it this way:

```js
    let args = [1, 2, 3];
    
    const myPromise = async x => console.log('arg:',x);
    
    const test = async () => {
      for (let task of args.map(myPromise)) 
        await task;
    }
  
    test().then(console.log('Done'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.24.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe your second example is not guaranteed to run sequentially.

Answer (score -2):

You can iterate over the array of elements and pass the params like this:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
const MyPromiseFunction = num => new Promise(
  (resolve, reject) =>
    // Your logic...
    setTimeout(() => num <= 4 
      ? resolve('Success!') 
      : reject('Rejected!'), 1000 * num)
)
const logMessage = (num, msg) => 
  console.log(`For number ${num} promise result: ${msg}`)

arr.map(
  async (num) => await MyPromiseFunction(num)
    .then(message => logMessage(num, message))
    .catch(reason => logMessage(num, reason))
)
```