# Unexpected Promise.all with nested map promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I need to display few messages of an array after 3 seconds utilizing `array.map()`. Here is the array:

```
const messages = [
    'hello', 'world', 'have', 'some', 'code'
]
```

In order to wait in the map i've created a `wait` function.

```
const wait = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(true)
    }, 3000)
})
```

Then, i have an `app` method where i've executed the `Promise.all()` like this,

```
const app = async () => {
    await Promise.all(messages.map(async msg => {
        await wait
        document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML += msg + ', '
    }))
}

app()
```

Expected output would be to wait for 3 seconds in every iteration of the map on the message array, but it will output all the messages at once after 3 seconds!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/rakibtg/pen/xQMwYK

What i'm missing here?

Comment: Once 3 seconds has passed `wait` is resolved... and awaiting it will complete immediately. You probably want a function to return a new promise each time.

Comment: It sounds like you're hoping for a sequence behavior? Promise.all() is good for doing something _after_ a group of async work finishes, but doesn't sound like the right fit here.

Comment: @stealththeninja Yes, i'm hoping for a sequence behavior

Comment: @Gerrit0 `wait` now should return a function each time, but works the same way. https://codepen.io/rakibtg/pen/xQMwYK

Comment: I think you miss this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707475/how-to-make-a-promise-from-settimeout

Comment: Thanks everyone, using a sync loop `for ( const item of messages )` solved the problem :)

Comment: @rakibtg awesome! Will you be posting an answer to your question?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082934/how-to-execute-promises-sequentially-passing-the-parameters-from-an-array

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all()` can be used to pass a list of promises, which all get waited on in parallel.

The code you shared does wait 3 seconds for every iteration, except all those iterations are all happening at the same time.

If you want to not do everything in parallel, but just handle one at a time you can rewrite this to a simple loop:

```
const app = async () => {
  for (const msg of messages) {
    await wait();
    document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML += msg + ', '
  }
}
```