# Database transactions happen parallely instead of sequentially in loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, knex.js

I have an endpoint which loops through an array and updates the database as follows.

```
 app.post('/create', Authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  const {
    products,
  } = req.body;
  const trxProvider = knex.transactionProvider();
  const trx = await trxProvider();

  try {
    const formattedProduct = await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {

     // Get Current value
      const warehouseProducts = await trx('warehouse_products')
        .select('available_qty as qty')
        .where('product_code', product.product.code)
        .first();

      const finalQty = warehouseProducts.qty - product.orderQty;

     // Update database
      await trx('warehouse_products')
        .update({ available_qty: finalQty })
        .where('product_code', product.product.code);
    }));
    await trx('ordered_products')
      .insert(formattedProduct);
    trx.commit();
    console.log('Transaction successful');
    return send(res, 201, { success: true });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    trx.rollback();
    const errors = {};
    errors.message = 'something went wrong';
    return send(res, 500, errors);
  }
});
```

The issue arises when i try to update the same row of the warehouse_products table within the loop. 
In the loop initially the *qty* value is taken from the warehouse_products table for a particular product then an arithmetic operation is done and the *qty* value is updated.

Ideally if both iterations access the same row, the second iteration's initial *qty* value should be what the first iteration updated. However the issue is that the second iteration too starts with the initial value of the first iteration. Its almost as if both iterations are happening parallel to each other instead of occurring sequentially.

Comment: if you are using `bluebird` promises, you could use `Promise.map` rather `Promise.all`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute promises sequentially, passing the parameters from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082934/how-to-execute-promises-sequentially-passing-the-parameters-from-an-array)

Comment: @AZ_ is there any other way to do it without using timeouts ? also is there a pure js implementation of Promise.map ?

Comment: `Promise.map` is not natively included in Javascript but will be in `ES2020`, if you dont want to use external library like `Bluebird` or `Async` you can go with simple `for loop`

Comment: I initially tried a for loop but i cant use async await inside right ? I also tried for each without Promise.all but when i do that the output gets sent before the loop finishes...

Comment: added a sample with `for-loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `Promise.all` it is supposed to happen in paralle. For sequential processing change this code

```
await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {
// logic here
});
```

to

```
for(const product of products) {
  // logic here
}
```

Comment: I need to use await to fetch database values. How to make this approach accommodate it ?

Comment: just put them inside the for loop. `for..of` loop supports await so yuo can just add the logic the same way you did using `romise.all`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the definition for [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

> It is typically used after having started multiple asynchronous tasks to run concurrently and having created promises for their results, so that one can wait for all the tasks being finished.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use an external library like `Bluebird` or `Async`

you can go with simple for a loop as following

```js
let delay = (t) => new Promise((resolve) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
  return resolve(new Date().getMilliseconds())
 }, t*1000);
});

let array = [1,1,1,1];

//using simple for loop
async function test() {
 let out = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  const res = await delay(array[i]);
  out.push(res);
 }
 return out;
}

test().then(res => {
 console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Whats the purpose of pushing res inside out ? also could you elaborate as to where i should include my db queries in the above snippet ?

Comment: if you want to chain the promises and return the final response, if not you simply can use `Array.reduce` for the `waterfall` model.