# JavaScript new promise-request

Tags: javascript, api, promise

I am facing an issue in JavaScript. I want to do change `promise.all` into single promise request.

What should I do? Anyone help me?

It just a sample code for understand:

**count:** (4) [Promise, Promise, Promise, Promise]

**data:** (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

```js
//send delivery report with send sms response                                
Promise.all(count).then(function(data) {
    var delivery_reports = [];
    console.log(data);
    SendDeliveryReport(data);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

// execute promises sequentially, passing the parameters from an array

```
            count.reduce(
            (p, x) =>
                p.then(_ => myPromise(x)),
             //send delivery report with send sms response                                
             Promise.all(count).then(function (data){
               var delivery_reports = [];
                console.log(data);
                SendDeliveryReport(data);
            })
            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            })
            
            )
```

Comment: What is `count`? `SendDeliveryReport`?

Comment: you can check a add count result [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking still. What's the problem with this current code? What does or doesn't work as expected? What do you want to change?

Comment: i want to change `promise.all` into `new promise` request [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

Comment: i want to send all  sms at one time sometime it gave `request timeout error` [@](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

Comment: How do you expect to change 4 requests into one without `Promise.all`? BTW you should be use `@username` to reply to someone, not a link to the user's profile.

Comment: i want to do handle 4 request one request `one by one save into new array` it is possible [@heretic-monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey)

Comment: First of all, are you talking about the `Promise.all(count)` part or the `SendDeliveryReport(data)` part? We don't know what any of those things do.

Comment: @adnankhan I don't think your problem is in **Promise.all** Promise.all is resolved when all the Promises are resolved

Comment: i am talking about `Promise.all(count)` part [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

Comment: @adnankhan maybe this will help you.If i'm getting it right [async/await with forEach()](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) , but you question is not very clear

Comment: OK, so you have a bunch of promises (`count`), and you want to turn them into one promise (?!), but without `Promise.all`, which is exactly the tool to aggregate many promises into one. … Why?

Comment: Are you saying that currently you're running all promises (network requests?) in parallel, but that's causing some to timeout, so you want to run them one after the other instead?

Comment: yes u r right [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

Comment: So, this then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43082995/476

Comment: ok thanks  i try [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)

Comment: i try in my code..i add in my code.. can u check it is ok ? [@deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze)