# Javascript await inside a loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to work with an api where I have to send a request for each item in a list.
However, I see that the loop doesn't seem to wait for every request, i.e, the loop doesn't work as expected. Here's the code below

```
getInfo = async () => {
   const mylist = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"]
   const responses = []
   const len = mylist.length
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      //console.log("inside loop")
      await axios.get("some_url/"+mylist[i])
          .then(res => {
              responses.push(res.data)
          })
   }
```

When I run the program, all the `console.log("inside loop")` executes immediately without waiting for the request to be complete.

How can I modify the code so as to wait for each response to be completed before updating the for loop counter variable?

Comment: You don't need to add `then` section when you use `async await` syntax. You can just put `console.log` after the await statement. `const res = await axios.get()`

Comment: The `.then()` usage is a bit weird (`cons res = await …; responses.push(res.data)` would be more idiomatic), but it should work as expected nonetheless. Is this your actual code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute promises sequentially, passing the parameters from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082934/how-to-execute-promises-sequentially-passing-the-parameters-from-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

You could try re-arranging the code to something like this. But using a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be more idiomatic solution for the problem.

`await` the `async` call (remove unnecessary `.then` call) and then `console.log`

```
getInfo = async () => {
   const mylist = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6","item7"]
   const responses = []
   const len = mylist.length
   for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      responses.push((await axios.get("some_url/"+mylist[i])).data)
      console.log("inside loop")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Internally, `await` is translated into a `Promise` chain. Since the `for` loop can't be transformed into a Promise-continuation, you'll need to convert it to a Promise-based construct.

Depending on what you want to achieve there are multiple ways to go about it.
Constructing the `responses` array could be done with a `map` statement.

```
const promises = mylist.map(item => {
   return axios.get("some_url/"+item).then(res => { return res.data; })
});
const data = await Promise.all(promises);
```

No manual pushing items around or fiddling with the array length.

Comment: "*Since the for loop can't be transformed into a Promise-continuation*" - of course it can?

Comment: The OP explicitly complains about "*all the `console.log("inside loop")` executes immediately without waiting for the request to be complete*", so no, they do **not** want the concurrent `Promise.all` solution! It should "*wait for each response to be completed before*" going to the next iteration.