# Sync + Async POSTing nested parent-children objects to preserve the order

Tags: javascript, performance, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I have a nested array of `Person` objects.

Each `Person` object has a mandatory `name`. Each `Person` can also optionally have a `children` field that contains an array of other `Person` objects (that also have a children field - so the "depth" of the family tree can essentially go on forever.)

If there is no children, the children field will just be an empty array [].

E.g.

```
  const family_name = "The Numbers";
  const family = [{
      name: "1",
      children: [],
    },
    {
      name: "2",
      children: [{
          name: "2-1",
          children: [{
            name: "2-1-1",
            children: [],
          }, ],
        },
        {
          name: "2-2",
          children: [],
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "3",
      children: [{
        name: "3-1",
        children: [],
      }, ],
    },
  ]
```

I need to POST the "parent" before the "child". When I POST a `Person`, I get its `id` back in the `response.data`. This `id` needs to be used in the immediate child's POST as a `parent_id` so that child will be associated to the parent.

The topmost `Person` will need to have their `parent_id` be the `family_name`.

**Each "level" needs to be POSTed asynchronously as my back-end needs to preserve the order.** (Note: Calculating the order of the `Person` on the client-side and passing that value to the back-end is not a solution as `Person` is actually a MPTT model where the insertion order matters.)

E.g. `1` then `2` then `3`

E.g. `2` then `2-1` then  `2-2`.

**However, the nested `Person`s can be POSTed in sync.** For example, once POSTing `2` returns with a 201 response, its "sibling" `3` and its "child" `2-1` can be POSTed at the same time.

How can I optimally POST all `Person`s in a nested array so that the order is preserved? Please note that I am using axios.

Edit: Here is some pseudo-code:

```
function postPersons(persons, parent_id) {
    // Async POST all objects in persons
    // e.g. POST 1 then 2 then 3 to family_name

    // For each successful POST, if person has children, 
    // async POST those children to that person
    // e.g. Once POST to 2 resolves, POST 2-1 then 2-2 to 2
    // e.g. Once POST to 3 resolves, POST 3-1 to 3

    // Repeat for all successful POSTs
    // e.g. Once POST to 2-1 resolves, POST 2-1-1 to 2-1

}

postPersons(family, family_name)
```

Comment: Have you written any code? We can't help debug code we can't see.

Comment: @Andy unfortunately I'm not even sure where to start. I've posted some pseudo-code if that will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `async`/`await` for a sequential loop, I'd recommend to use a synchronous loop and accumulate two things separately:

- the promise for the child that is processed sequentially (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24586168/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43082934/1048572))
- an array of promises for all the recursive calls, that will be `Promise.all`'d in the end

This ensures proper order as well as immediate propagation of errors.

So the code will look like

```
function postPersons(persons, parent_id) {
    const results = [];
    let chain = Promise.resolve();
    for (const person of persons) {
        chain = chain.then(() =>
            postSinglePerson(person, parent_id)
        );
        results.push(chain.then(result =>
            postPersons(person.children, result.id)
        ));
    }
    return Promise.all(results);
}
postPersons(family, family_name).then(() => console.log('Done'), console.error);
```