# Chaining setTimeout Calls Recursively with Javascript Callbacks

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, callback, settimeout

I have a simple setTimeout function in Javascript that just allows me to specify the amount of time to delay whatever action by and then just a callback to use for chaining

```
function delay(item, callback) {
    return new Promise(function(response, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(item.message);
            response(callback());
        }, item.time);
    });
}
```

I'm able to use it fine with nesting callbacks but it starts to become very tedious and ugly to use for longer chains

```
function delayChain() {

    const items = [
        {message:"Waited 01 sec", time:1000},
        {message:"Waited 02 sec", time:2000},
        {message:"Waited 04 sec", time:4000},
        {message:"Waited 03 sec", time:3000}
    ];

    delay(items[0], function() {
        delay(items[1], function() {
            delay(items[2], function() {
                delay(items[3], function() {
                    console.log("Done Waiting");
                });
            });
        });
    });

}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do something similar but in a recursive way

*UPDATE*

It seems that something similar can be done without the need of callbacks by using async/await like this

```
async function delayChainAsync() {

    const items = [
        {message:"Waited 01 sec", time:1000},
        {message:"Waited 02 sec", time:2000},
        {message:"Waited 04 sec", time:4000},
        {message:"Waited 03 sec", time:3000}
    ];

    for(let item of items) {
        await delay(item, function() {});
    }

    console.log("Done Waiting");

}
```

But I'm hoping to still make use of the callback chaining like in the original delay function

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50319656/283366) from the duplicate looks like what you want

Comment: This answer is close but it seems to not be making use of callbacks though, I'm just updating my question to put a bit more emphasis on the callbacks instead of async/await

Comment: Is using Promise ok? Or do you only want a solution with plain callbacks?

Comment: The Promise is mostly just to ensure that the callback is delayed for testing purposes but the callback is the mvp

Comment: I'm reopening this question as it has been clarified that it is mainly about callbacks instead of promises/async/await (which the answers in the duplicate are referring to)

Comment: @NickParsons thank you! I should have been a bit more clear but I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to create the nested functions using a loop on `items`. The idea is to loop backward through `items`, creating the most inner nested function first, and keeping a reference to it so that when you move to the next item down your array, you can create the next nested function that uses the previous one you created as the callback to `delay`. Once the loop is finished, you can call the final function you created to initiate the outer most function to begin the callback chain:

```js
function delay(item, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(item.message);
    callback();
  }, item.time);
}

function delayChain() {
  const items = [ {message:"Waited 01 sec", time:1000}, {message:"Waited 02 sec", time:2000}, {message:"Waited 04 sec", time:4000}, {message:"Waited 03 sec", time:3000} ];
  
  let nextFn = () => console.log("Done waiting"); // the most inner nested function
  for(let i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const ref = nextFn; // required so that the closure below refers to this current function and doesn't change as we update `nextFn` through our loop iterations
    nextFn = function() {
      delay(items[i], ref);
    };
  }
  nextFn();
}

delayChain();
```

Another option is to do this "pseudo recursively" by passing a counter/index to `delayChain` to determine which object we need to create the `delay` for in each new call to `delayChain`:

```js
function delay(item, callback) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(item.message);
    callback();
  }, item.time);
}

function delayChain(i = 0) {
  const items = [ {message:"Waited 01 sec", time:1000}, {message:"Waited 02 sec", time:2000}, {message:"Waited 04 sec", time:4000}, {message:"Waited 03 sec", time:3000} ];

  if(i === items.length)
    console.log("Done waiting"); // the most inner nested function
  else
    delay(items[i], () => delayChain(++i)); // recursively call `delayChain`
}

delayChain();
```

Also, note that your `delay` function does not need to return a Promise. As you're trying to work with callbacks, there is no need for it to return a `Promise` as that `Promise` value is never used. Most of the time, your function should either accept a callback as an argument *or* return a promise, but not both.

Comment: These look like exactly what I was hoping for (I didn't consider the Promise conflicting with the callback so thanks for that heads up too!)